# Chromium when maximized has gaps at the sides in Awesome WM

Tags: chrome, awesome

There are 1-2 px gaps between a maximized Chromium window and screen's border. As a result when I put my mouse on the border the Chromium window loses focus, or if I'm using my mouse wheel it changes tags. This doesn't happen if I unmaximize Chromium and stretch it out, but it's annoying. If I am not mistaken this happens with the default `rc.lua`. Awesome 3.4.